# Ruby-Processing : Undefined method error

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to run a ruby-processing file

```
vishrut@vishrut-XPS-L501X:~/Twitter-Emotion-Graphs/samples/contributed$ rp5 run sand_traveler.rb 
undefined method `current' for Processing::App:Class
    ./sand_traveler.rb:63:in `initialize'
    ./sand_traveler.rb:43:in `reset_all'
    org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java:256:in `times'
    ./sand_traveler.rb:40:in `reset_all'
    ./sand_traveler.rb:22:in `setup'
    /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/ruby-processing-1.0.11/lib/ruby-processing/app.rb:211:in `handleDraw'
```

Context and code for sand_traveler.rb : http://ashkenas.com/codework/ruby-processing.html

I am pretty sure all necessary modules have been installed (java, ruby, ruby-processing)
I am able to run other other ruby-processing .rb files using rp5. Only this one is showing  errors.

PS: Does the file location matter? The file is in my home folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing line 63 of `sand_traveler.rb`:

```
@app = Processing::App.current
```

with:

```
@app = $app
```

I get the same error as you, and this fixed it for me. (`$app` is global handle to the running sketch, which is also what `Processing::App.current` should do -- see [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/blob/master/CHANGELOG) entry for v0.3).

As to why it doesn't work -- it seems this method has been removed from the latest version of `ruby-processing`. If you look at [version 0.8](https://github.com/jashkenas/ruby-processing/tags) for example, `Processing::App` defines a class method on line 40 of `ruby-proccessing.rb`:

```
    def self.current; @current_app; end
```

Such a method is missing in the latest version.